# Java libGDX Box2D: can you set center of mass manually?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, center

As title asks, can you change the center of mass of a body, or is it stuck with the automatic calculation of center?

I could probably do it with multiple fixtures, but is there another way to manually set the center?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the center of mass like so

```
    b2MassData* data;
    body->GetMassData(data);
    data->center.Set(0, 0);
    body->SetMassData(data);
```

Comment: I get "The final field MassData.center cannot be assigned"

Comment: I made a quick change, since the MassData's center variable is final it cannot be changed to a new Vector2 instead you can set position of the Vector2 with .set(x,y)